# KeyDown not firing for Up, Down, Left and Right

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, keydown

On a form I have a panel with some buttons. When button1 is clicked I replace the panel with a new UserControl which has a label (e.g. `this.Controls.Clear()`, `this.Controls.Add(UserControl1)`). Except the label on my userControl has a KeyDown handler. It works fine, the event fires, but not for keys Up, Down, Left and Right. Can anybody explain why there is a difference between these keys? What decides whether the event is fired or not?

Comment: Please show use some code for the handler you have written so far

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two basic reasons.  First the mysterious one: a Label control cannot receive the focus so can't see keystrokes.  The reason its KeyDown event is hidden in the designer.  Not so sure why you see any keystrokes at all.  The more common reason is that the cursor and TAB keys are used for navigation, moving the focus from one control to another.  Which is done *before* the key is passed to the control.  You'd have to override the control so you can override its IsInputKey() method.  But more practically you'd override the UserControl's ProcessCmdKey() instead to solve both issues.

Also note that you've got a nasty handle leak in your program.  *Never* call Controls.Clear() without also calling the Dispose() method on the controls you remove.  Unless you intended to reuse them later, not so common.  It is a nasty kind of leak that the garbage collector doesn't solve and ultimately crashes your program after first making it slow and unwieldy.

Comment: That's it! Because the KeyDown event was hidden by buttons (to navigate through the buttons using keys: Up, Down, Left Right, Tab and Enter to click) the event didn't fired. Calling panel.Dispose() before clearing the controls solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.keydown%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> This event supports the .NET Framework infrastructure **and is not intended to be used directly from your code**.
>
> Occurs when the user presses a key while the label has focus.

Edit:  There doesn't seem to be an alternative event for this.  From what I've read, arrows keys should definitely be detected.  Please supply some code.

Answer (score 1):

You should override method ProcessCmdKey instead. Arrow keys are not processed the same way as other standard keys. Another solution would be this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx suggested by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

To handle arrow keys you may either set the Form's KeyPreview property to true and then handle them at form level instead specific control level. I have done so and it works perfect!

In case, above does not work for you then consider `ProcessCmdKey` something like this:

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData) 
{

       if(KeyData == Keys.Right)
       {
        //Move Right
         return true;
         }
        else
        {
         return base.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData);
        }

 }
```

Comment: You have not mentioned where your events are being handled inside user control or on host form? in case they are being handled on host form then you will need to re-register all events to event handles upon adding new instance of user control.