# intercepting KeyDown event on a WinForm when Trackbar exists

Tags: c#, winforms

This is ridiculous. I have a KeyDown event I am interested in(to get DownArrow Key event) for a WinForm. I added a trackbar, which gets Autofocus(I dont know how). And now, when I press the DOWN arrow key - it automatically changes the value of the Trackbar and my code for the Winform is not working. I tried HIDING the Trackbar with a button but to no avail. I even have

```
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

in my Form1_KeyDown() handler.

Help, I am going haywire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override ProcessCmdKey method. check out below links for more information.

[Up, Down, Left and Right arrow keys do not trigger KeyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event)

http://www.getdotnetcode.com/gdncstore/free/Articles/Overriding%20a%20Controls%20ProcessCmdKey%20Function.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: unfortunately, UP|DOWN|LEFT|RIGHT /are/ triggering KeyDown() events, and they're being consumed by Trackbar. I found a solution around it. It is to Override KeyDown() event for the trackbar and call Form1_KeyDown() event instead.

Comment: Have you checked with ProcessCmdKey() method? if you pressed any key on form this method will execute if you override it in your form codebehind file.