# Detecting arrows keys in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, keypress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Up, Down, Left and Right arrow keys do not trigger KeyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event)

First see the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
namespace winform_project
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
 }
}
```

I am able to detect alpha-numeric keys. However i am not able to detect arrow keys.

Any help would be appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok so after some research i found out the simplest way to handle arrow key events is to override the ProcessCmdKey method.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
     if(keyData == Keys.Left)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("You pressed Left arrow key");
       return true;
     }
     return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Hope this helps.