# Set Arrow Keys As Input Keys - WinForms

Tags: c++, winforms

I need to detect arrow keystrokes in the `KeyDown` event. I do understand that they need to be set as input keys but I'm not clear on how to accomplish it in C++ . Found good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163447/detecting-arrows-keys-in-winforms) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163447/detecting-arrows-keys-in-winforms). But that is C# and I need C++. Tried implementing like described [here](http://www.codeease.com/arrow-keys-can-not-be-captured-in-keydown-event.html) have this code in `PreviewKeyDown` but no luck.

```
switch (e->KeyCode)
{
    case Keys::Down:
    case Keys::Up:
    case Keys::Right:
    case Keys::Left:
    case Keys::Space:
    e->IsInputKey = true;
       break;
}
```

and my `KeyDown` have :

```
if (e->KeyCode == Keys::Left)
{
    ///
}
```

Which is not working on pressing left.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you want us to say? You already linked the relevant links that answer your question. Consider posting your code, and describing the problem completely. :)

Comment: Im sorry if Im not clear enough. I want to implement it in c++. I dont know how to translate the code in the links for cpp..and my problem is, to be more clear, the KeyDown event is detecting all the keys except the arrow keys, return, tab and space.. so i think what i need is the cpp code to properly override the IsInputKey property

Comment: You don't override it, you should call it in previewkeydown, as explained in your last link ;)

Comment: well , i said i tried taht...this is the code in my previewkeydown. doesnt work..   previewkeydown

Comment: switch (e->KeyCode)
 {
 case Keys::Down:
 case Keys::Up:
 case Keys::Right:
 case Keys::Left:
 case Keys::Space:
  e->IsInputKey = true;
  break;
 }

Comment: Edit your question then :)

Comment: Do you have something in keydown??

Comment: yes there is..ive updated the question..

Comment: You are using C++/CLI with WinForms. The code is almost ***identical*** to the C# code. The only thing you have to change from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5606692/366904) is `Keys.Xxx` to `Keys::Xxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

For anyone facing the same, it worked when I added events `PreviewKeydown` and `KeyDown` events with the same code, for **each of the controls** in the form, but not for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++ example of how to capture Key presses:
[C++ Detect when user presses arrow key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708700/c-detect-when-user-presses-arrow-key)

And here is the MSDN doc for the KeyDown event with some C++ code examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

hope that helps.

Comment: I saw that one..but im not on working on a console application..its a forms application. But thnx for the second link.