# KeyUp event firing from next control

Tags: c#, winforms

I've 5 buttons in my windows application. When I click arrow keys the focus changing between buttons, then only

> KeyUp

event firing. How to stop this?

Comment: I want the KeyUp event to be fired from exact button which had focus when I pressed the Arrow key.

Comment: It is default behavior. When you press arrow key focus will change to next control and then you release key so you got `KeyUp` event from next Button. If you don't release key for long time it will continues focus change from one to another control and when you release key you will get `KeyUp` event from focused control.

Comment: @Sameer ya correct, But my question is how to stop the default behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead.

> Occurs before the KeyDown event when a key is pressed while focus is on this control.

As you move through the buttons, the `sender` parameter will contain the previously selected button.

---

I found a solution that should work for you, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event). Apparently, MS made the decision that the arrow keys wouldn't trigger the `KeyDown` event, so you can't cancel them.

One workaround is to specify that your arrow keys are normal input keys, like any other key. Then the `KeyDown` event will fire and you can cancel the button press if you want.

```
private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        e.IsInputKey = true;
}

private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

You may want to read the other answers and comments in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event) to see what would work best in your situation.

Comment: Can you tell What I'm supposed to do in PreviewKeyDown to stop the focus moving to next control?

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. But I found this before you posted. Anyway  good to show the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question in comment

```
    void button1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: It only focus the button1 every time. Actually I want the focus on the button in which I pressed the arrow key.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent <kbd>Up</kbd> from moving focus from a `Button` you have to utilize at least 3 methods:

```
    bool _focus;

    private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            _focus = true;
    }

    private void button1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _focus = false;
    }

    private void button1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_focus)
            button1.Focus(); // or (sender as Control)
    }
```

Trick is to use flag when user press <kbd>Up</kbd> and to return focus in `Leave`. You have to unflag in `KeyUp`, otherwise it would be impossible to change focus (by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to example).

You could possible unflag in `Leave`, I didn't test it.