# Why KeyDown event doesn't catch "Control" downs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, keydown

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            this.Text = "up";
            break;

        case Keys.Down:
            this.Text = "down";
            break;

        case Keys.Left:
            this.Text = "<-";
            break;

        case Keys.Right:
            this.Text = "->";
            break;

        case Keys.Delete:
            this.Text = "delete";
            break;

        case Keys.Control:
            this.Text = "control";
            break;

        case Keys.Control | Keys.C:
            this.Text = "control + c";
            break;

        case Keys.Control | Keys.X:
            this.Text = "control + x";
            break;

        case Keys.Control | Keys.V:
            this.Text = "control + v";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Everything that related to holding Control do not displays in form header...
This is just code example and not real project. In real project I need to catch Control + C / X / V presses to do copy / paste operations.

Comment: You are just testing for the wrong key.  If you want to see the Ctrl key itself, rather than just the modifier, then you'll have to test for Keys.ControlKey.  There is no point to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution :

```
case (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
```

**EDIT :**
if it not works, add paranthesis around your code :

```
case (Keys.Control | Keys.C):
```

**EDIT 2 :**
and this one :

```
e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V)
```

**EDIT 3:**
switch on KeyData

```
switch (keyData) {
   // Control+ C
   case Keys.Control | Keys.C:
      // ...
      break;
   case Keys.Control | Keys.V:
      // ...
      break;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, did you tested by yourself the compile ability of your examples? The one in comment and this one is uncompilable. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'`. And the `(Keys.Control | Keys.C)` is same result as my original code.

Comment: my first solution is normal able to compile if you use `KeyDown` event
the sencond, I think the miss of paranthesis are cause

Comment: are you using `winforms` ?

Comment: `if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V)) this.Text = "control + v";` This works... But how do make it work in switch case?

Comment: whereas to switch `KeyCode`, switch `KeyData`

Comment: This works, but weird. It still no capture `case Keys.Control:`

Comment: to capture, I think you can override this : 
`protected override bool ProcessCmdKey (ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
   switch ( keyData )
   {
      case Keys.F4 | Keys.Control: 
         // Do something
   }

}`

you have an other solution here :-D : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event`

Comment: Ughh I will think about it. But now I already happy. `case Keys.Control:` is for future. Thank you.