# C# Forms App Executing Task.Run stops the rest of the code execution

Tags: c#, winforms, task

Excuse for the code it is a mess but I'm trying to figure things out without much use of google.

**Problem**: I have an `OnKeyDown` method this starts moving my square on the screen to the right, I want to so if a user presses `A` for it to stop and move to the left. I really don't know what I'm doing here but I thought if I use a `Task.Run` I can listen for other inputs and if a key is pressed it can return `true` and break from the while loop and I would call another method to move left. This is probably a very wrong approach but I'm really stuck here and I don't know another way to do this yet.

Many thanks in advance.

**All Coded added**: Only other bits in here are a draw Grid method and OnPaint Method

```
public Form1()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(221, 221, 221);
    this.CenterToScreen();
    this.NumCells = (int)Math.Floor((float)this.ClientSize.Width / CellSize);
}
```

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs pe)
{ 
    Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

    for (int i = 1; i < NumCells; i++)
    {
        //Vertical Lines
        g.DrawLine(BlackPen, i * CellSize, 0, i * CellSize, NumCells * CellSize);

        //Horizontal Lines
        g.DrawLine(BlackPen, 0, i * CellSize, NumCells * CellSize, i * CellSize);
    }
}
```

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);

    Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 20);

    if (this.Move == true)
    {
        var lpnt1 = new PointF(X * CellSize / 2, Y1 * 1);
        var lpnt2 = new PointF(X * CellSize / 2, Y2 * 1);
        g.DrawLine(blackPen, lpnt1, lpnt2);
    }

    Log(); //Custom `Debug.WriteLine` string to log current variables.
}
```

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs ke)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(ke);

    if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.D) 
    {
        this.Move = true;

        while (this.Move == true)
        {
            var t1 = Task.Run(bool () =>
            {
                if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                    return true;
                else return false;
            });

            if (t1.Result == true)
                break;

            if (X > this.NumCells * 2)
            {
                X = 1;
                this.Invalidate();
                this.Update();
                break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(Velocity);

            X += MoveX;
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach cannot work because your while-loop runs all the time and prevents the app from interacting with the rest of the operating system.

Comment: For an easy example how to move around something with cursor keys on a winform, see this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74138565/check-collision-and-prevent-overlap/74139557#74139557

Comment: `t1.Result` causes a deadlock, use `async/await`.

Comment: What is this `Task.Run(bool () =>` syntax? This doesn't seem like real code to me.

Comment: "if I use a `Task.Run` I can listen for other inputs" - No, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is not the `Task.Run` - it's that you're blocking the UI from properly responding to all updates on the message pump.

This code:

```
var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        return true;
    else return false;
});

if (t1.Result == true)
    break;
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.D)
    break;
```

The `Task` is doing nothing of value here.

Your problem is the `while` loop that doesn't return control to the message pump. Instead of a loop, you need a timer that does your moves.

Here's how:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer = null;
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs ke)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(ke);

    if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    if (_timer == null)
    {
        _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        _timer.Interval = Velocity;
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.X =
                this.X > this.NumCells * 2
                ? 1
                : this.X + this.MoveX;
        };
    }

    if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.D)
    {
        _timer.Enabled = !_timer.Enabled;
    }
}
```

When enabled, the timer is fired every `Velocity` milliseconds and updates `this.X`. Hitting the `D` key toggles the timer on and off. Simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I think I understand the concept but it doesn't work... I wrote the exact code you've done and I keep getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and idk why  I've tried fixing it but nothing. Also is it possible you can elaborate on the `lambda` inside the `if (_timer == null)` I don't understand that syntax, what type of syntax is that so I can research it.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist - Where are you getting that error?

Comment: This error occurs on line `this.Container.Add(_timer);`

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist - Just take that out and make sure you dispose of the timer properly when the form closes.

Comment: I will try that as soon as I get home this evening. If everything works I will upvote and accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: After trying for about half hour with different things. Doesn't work. I do not have a clue why but I will look into timers and once I fix it I will post an extra comment with link to code so you can possibly update your answer. Thanks

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist - Can you please elaborate on "doesn't work'? Now, just as a suggestion for future questions, when you provide a [mcve] in your question then it makes it much easier for people answering to fully test the code before posting. Right now you need to retrofit my code into yours and I don't know if any of the assumptions I made about your code hold. You are then debugging a hybrid of your code and mine - and who knows what it might look like when it runs.

Comment: I will update my question with the rest of the code in the form. There is nothing much more in here trust me.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist - Please start a new Windows Forms project and then copy and paste in only the code you've added to the question. When you run it you'll find all sorts of errors. A [mcve] is code with no errors. Can you please provide that?