# How to make a keypress in Winforms call a function

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form that I need to take a arrow key press and then call a function passing it a result deppending on what arrow key was pressed. I have the code for inside the function but I just don't know how to pickup the key press in the first place.

So I think the name/inputs of the second function are wrong.

What i currently have is:

```
        public void ShowGame(string Level)
    {
        FormGame frmGame = new FormGame();
        frmGame.SetLevel(Level);
        frmGame.ShowDialog();

    }


    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            Controller.PassMove(Direction.Up);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            Controller.PassMove(Direction.Down);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            Controller.PassMove(Direction.Left);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            Controller.PassMove(Direction.Left);
        }
    }
```

so that top function I have is one that opens up a new form window on top of my base main one which I have a feeling might be blocking the keypress detection.
The second function is the one i want to be called when a arrow keypress is made.
I am pretty sure my internals of the second function are correct but when I open and debug the code and put a debug stopper on the start of that function and press a key it never calls that second function.

so I was just wondering if anyone can help me with the detection of key presses and how that works I have looked at so many resources but none seem to like winforms.

Comment: try using the form's keydown event instead of a textbox's

Comment: did you check this SO thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event

Comment: That Thread solved it thanks so much I dont know how I couldnt find that