# Handle pressing up arrow on keyboard when focus is on button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to catch when the user is pressing the up arrow on the keyboard, while the button has the focus. I have written this code to handle the KeyUp event for the button:

```
private void btnValider_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

but this function didn't handle pressing the up arrow key.

I don't know if it what i want to do is possible or if i have to handle this event from the form ?

Comment: In your form add `PreviewKey = true;` while initialized. Then you can check for input in your form like `void meForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { if(btnValidaer.HasFocus) { /*logic here*/ } }` Or you can add `IMessageFilter` interface, or you can override `WndProc(ref Message msg)` method

Comment: See the [documentation for `KeyUp`:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) - _"Certain keys, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and **arrow keys** are handled by controls automatically. To have these keys raise the KeyUp event, you must override the IsInputKey method in each control on your form. The code for the override of IsInputKey would need to determine if one of the special keys is pressed and return a value of true."_

Comment: @m.rogalski PreviewKey is available only on Form and it doesn't help catching arrow keys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event/

Comment: @Kodre that's why i posted 3 methods. Besides I dont know what he was able to research till now. So answer will be unclear since it's a guess game.

Comment: The arrow keys and Tab are used for navigation.  So you'll never get that event, it is intercepted before it can reach the button.  Using KeyPreview is not a fix either.  It isn't very clear what Keys.Up needs to do so the best solution is not obvious.  Override ProcessCmdKey() for the universal fix.

Comment: @hans : What i put on ProcessCmdKey. I have already override it to for keys.Tab : if (keyData == Keys.Tab). Should i have to put  if (keyData == Keys.Tab) also ?

Comment: `// do stuff`.  Why SO users refuse to document their code and insist on only getting guesses instead of answers is something I'll never understand.

Comment: @Hans: i have not yet write the code // do stuff, because  i am wondering how to solve my problem. But it's not relevant to the problem itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) suggested,

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Up && btnValider.Focused)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hit");

            return true;
        }
        else
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: it is not obliged to add the '&& btnValider.Focused'. 'if (keyData == Keys.Up)' is enough. I have test it.

Answer (score -1):

handle key down event for the button.

Comment: Same problem: _" Certain keys, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys are handled by controls automatically. To have these keys raise the **KeyDown event** … "_