# The Arrow Keys makes my "KeyEventArgs" to "not" work

Tags: c#, pong

I'm very new to programming and I'm currently doing a Pong project and as I was trying the program out for the first time I noticed that if I press an Arrow Key the other keys would stop working. Why is that?

The KeyEventArgs

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) upKeyPressed = true;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) downKeyPressed = true;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) paused = !paused;
}

protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyUp(e);
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) upKeyPressed = false;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) downKeyPressed = false;
}
```

so basically I'm using 'W' and 'S' to move my "paddles" but as soon as I press an arrow key the W and the S stops working...

The code I use to move my paddle with W and S:

```
private void moveBall(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //If not paused we can "start" the game
    if (!paused)
    {
        //Player 1
        if (upKeyPressed && Paddle1.Location.Y > topBounds)
        {
            Paddle1.Location = new Point(Paddle1.Location.X, Paddle1.Location.Y - 5);
        }
        else if (downKeyPressed && (Paddle1.Location.Y + Paddle1.Height) < bottomBounds)
        {
            Paddle1.Location = new Point(Paddle1.Location.X, Paddle1.Location.Y + 5);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a timer with the interval of 1 for the code above
And then it's just a paddle in a picturebox as the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6DZ8.png) shows

I don't know how much you need to be able to see what the problem is but I can obviously take more pictures or upload the whole program.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We invite you to take the [tour] and take some tips on [ask]. Don't post you code as picture, paste it as text (so we can copy and try it out).

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7815185/15920836) Stackoverflow post by Rodolfo Neuber.

```
I recently stumbled across this article from microsoft, which looks quite
promising: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx
According to microsoft, the best thing to do is set 
e.IsInputKey=true; in the PreviewKeyDown event after detecting 
the arrow keys. Doing so will fire the KeyDown event.

This worked quite well for me and was less hack-ish than overriding the ProcessCMDKey.
```

For context, this means you create another listner `PreviewKeyDown`, and in it set the parameter (`KeyDownEvent`) to have `IsInputKey` be true.

This then reads your arrow's `onKeyDownEvent` as the arrowkey being pressed into the program, rather than the OS.

As an example, think about how you can `alt-tab` in any window and it isn't read by the program, but instead by windows itself, changing active window.

Arrow keys obviously work the same way.