# Keyboard management in a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to put keyboard management in the form of my program to set up shortcuts.
So I've declared this

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
}
```

then in my program

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
              // My code
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work, I keep hitting the down key, nothing!
I put a stop at:

```
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
```

It never does. The only thing that works is the space bar, as if I were clicking on the last button used.
Thanks for your advice

Comment: does your form have the focus? Chances are some of its controls have it, or another form, which both would prevent you from capturing key-events on the forms event-handler.

Comment: In this case, how to transfer the focus on the form? I have tried Form1.Focus() but it is recognize by the compiler.

Comment: You presumably don't want to move focus away from a control on your form that feels very annoying. Have a look at [KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) so the form gets those events first before the actual control with the focus. Is there a reaon doing it yourself? Shortcut are build in via mnemonics.

Comment: Some keys are handled differently in Winforms (like the Down Key) as they do things that might influence focus etc and are considered problematic. You need to make sure that the keys you want to handle actually end up in the KeyDown Event. that is done either by  defining those keys as "normal" via overriding [IsInputKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) or by handling those special keys in [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: It's working perfectly with a lot of key, but it doesn't work with the arrows keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646998/14171304

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Up, Down, Left and Right arrow keys do not trigger KeyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make some hot key shortcuts is to implement `IMessageFilter` which installs the `PreFilterMessage` hook for the entire form regardless of which control has focus.

[image: Hot key demo]

---

In the constructor, add the message filter and set it to remove when the form disposes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        // Hook the message filter here.
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);

        // Unhook the message filter when this form disposes.
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);

        button1.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("Clicked or CTRL-M");
    }
    ...
}
```

---

In the method, screen for the Win32 key down message.

```
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                var e = new KeyEventArgs(((Keys)m.WParam) | Control.ModifierKeys);
                OnHotKeyPreview(FromHandle(m.HWnd), e);
                return e.Handled;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

Then implement a custom hot key detector for the shortcuts that are of interest to you.

```
    private void OnHotKeyPreview(Control? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Control | Keys.M:
                button1.PerformClick();
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            case Keys.Control | Keys.R:
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                richTextBox1.AppendText($"{nameof(Color.Red)} {Environment.NewLine}");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            case Keys.Control | Keys.G:
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
                richTextBox1.AppendText($"{nameof(Color.Green)} {Environment.NewLine}");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            case Keys.Control | Keys.B:
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                richTextBox1.AppendText($"{nameof(Color.Blue)} {Environment.NewLine}");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Down:
                richTextBox1.AppendText($"{e.KeyData} {Environment.NewLine}");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```