# Panel.TabStop = true has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, tabstop

I Trying to switch `Panel.TabStop` property to`true` but it does not affect anything.

How to enable `TabStop` in a `Panel`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Panel not getting focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus)

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks, I found the answer there, I just needed to add this line to my ctor: `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);`

Comment: Well, don't cut it short.  The user not being able to see the focus isn't great.

Comment: I'll do the necessary things in `OnPaint`, this is not a problem for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

A Panel does not accept keyboard focus because a Panel is not a control (per se), it's a container for other controls which probably accept keyboard focus.

If you're trying to create a custom control, derive from UserControl or Control.

Answer (score 1):

The TabStop property has no effect on the Panel control as it is a container object.

Checkout this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbsx4akz.aspx) for details.

Comment: Not sure that is accurate. If you set Focusable=True then you can tab to a Panel no problems

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, the panel control will not accept focus. However, if you set TabStop to true and set its TabOrder, then the next control in the TabOrder should receive focus.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the TabStop property exists at the control level, but it really only affects what I would call interactive controls (there's probably an actual, correct term).   Since panels can't directly receive the focus, they won't behave differently based on that flag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put something that can accept focus onto it, like editbox.  There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Focusable=true` for the Panel you are using.