# Event to know if Panel lost focus in Winforms application?

Tags: winforms, focus, panel

I have a simple Form with 4 panels in it. Each of those panels are docked in the parent, to ensure only one is visible at a given time. Now, for Panel2, when it is moving from front to back, I would like to work on that event. I am making panels visible by calling `panel.BringToFront()`
I have tried `Leave` event but that doesn't work. For Form, the event is `Deactivate`, what's the event for Panel?

Comment: Panel doesn't want the focus, it is a container control.  There isn't anything useful that it could do with the focus.  Not sure why you try, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus/3562449#3562449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking `LostFocus` is what you're looking for.

### Edit

As another strategy, you know that calling `panel.BringToFront` will queue an update in your UI. Wherever you are calling `panel.BringToFront`, perhaps you could just call one of your own methods, or trigger one of your own events. This way, you *know* when the event will be triggered, and exactly *what* will trigger it.

The reason I thought of this is that I doubt your `Panel` will ever actually have the focus itself - rather, one of its child controls will likely have the focus. By doing you own event trigger, you don't have to rely on something as volatile as focus. Plus, even if the `Panel` did have the focus, it's always possible that it could lose focus in other ways than your own panel switching.

### Edit #2

Here's an attempt at a quick implementation of my previous ramblings. I'll be making the assumption that this code be placed somewhere in the same class as all your `Panel` instances (i.e. in your `Form` class).

```
// This will be the custom event to which you can subscribe
// in order to detect a switch in panels.
public event EventHandler PanelSwapEvent;

// This reference the currently visible panel - should be set
// to the default panel in the form's constructor, if possible.
private Panel currentPanel;

// This actually switches the panels, to minimize code duplication.
private void switchToPanel(Panel p)
{
    Panel lastPanel = currentPanel;
    currentPanel = p;

    // Move the panels, and invoke the event.

    p.BringToFront();
    if(PanelSwapEvent != null)
        PanelSwapEvent(lastPanel, new EventArgs());
}

// Here's the actual event handler (replaces your
// pnlServiceInfo_LostFocus handler).
private void PanelSwapHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // whatever you want to do when panels are swapped
}
```

In this example, the `sender` of the event handler is the panel that lost "focus". Using it is as simple as saying `switchToPanel(pnl_whatever)` to indicate that you would like to switch from the current panel to the panel named `pnl_whatever`.

Comment: Yes, see [Panel Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel_events.aspx) at MSDN. I believe it does not appear in the VS property box, because it has `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]`.

Comment: Nice to know that. But it still  doesn't work. This is my code.`private void pnlServiceInfo_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi!");
        }` also registered the event.`this.pnlServiceInfo.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.pnlServiceInfo_LostFocus);`

Comment: See my edit - I think this explains the problem more correctly, in a way that will actually solve your problem.

Comment: I too was worried about panel's focus, 'cos its one of it's child controls that will get the focus. While dropping in at each bringToFront() does precisely what I want, it is a rather tedious job. Because I actually have 14 panels. And that might increase over time! I would like to have the code at 1 place. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I'll see if I can't whip up an example.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2082/discussion-between-reddy-s-r-and-ken-wayne-vanderlinde)

Comment: Here, `if (PanelSwapEvent != null)`, PaenlSwapEvent is always null. Why?

Comment: Thanks for your time Ken. I have used your code but moved the Event thing out and just used SwapPanel than calling BringToFront() directly and got what I want.