# Not receiving WM_KEYDOWN message in a Panel's overloaded WndProc?

Tags: .net, panel, wndproc

I am receiving other types of messages, so I know the overloaded method is being called.

The only info I have found from searching talks about needing to give my Panel focus so that it can receive inputs. However, that solution did not help anything. (http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/44/221762.aspx)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do I need to provide any additional info? Is my questions maybe too vague? Or too specific?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Panel not getting focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus)

Comment: Hans, your post link worked great and ended up being a better solution then the one I found. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was related to the Panel not having focus.

A Panel (and some other types of controls) can not receive certain types of inputs because it can not receive proper focus.

I just changed the type from a Panel to a Button and things worked.

This was acceptable for me since I am only using this control as a tick/render surface anyways.