# WinForm Resizing a panel onFocus

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Panel not getting focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus)

im test the Panel control in winform, and I got into a problem.

i have this 2 events that i added to the panel but non of them fire:

```
 private void panel_onFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Size = new Size(panel1.Size.Width, panel1.Size.Height * panel1.Size.Height);
    }

    private void panel_lostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Size = new Size(panel1.Size.Width, panel1.Size.Height / panel1.Size.Height);
    }
```

i got a another control on the Form to test the focus(a button).

why onFocus and lostFocus dosnt fire?

(sory for my english)

Comment: hmmm... Im not sure (its been a while), but can a panel even have focus?

Comment: thx i didnt know that panels cant have focus.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a selectable panel (inherited from regular panel)

Got from [Panel not getting focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus/3562449#3562449)

Try this. Add this class in your project. Just changing `namespace yourApplicaionName`. Compile your project. Then you would see `selectablePanel` in your toolbox. You can use it instead of normal panel. Hope you will be able to get focus on this panel

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace yourApplicaionName
{
    class selectablePanel : Panel
    {
        public selectablePanel()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);            
            ResizeRedraw = true;
            this.TabStop = true;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Focus();
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Up || keyData == Keys.Down) return true;
            if (keyData == Keys.Left || keyData == Keys.Right) return true;
            return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
            base.OnEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
            base.OnLeave(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
            if (this.Focused)
            {
                var rc = this.ClientRectangle;
                rc.Inflate(-2, -2);
                ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, rc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks mostly copied from [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/719186).  You should attribute the code to him.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @LarsTech ... I had lost the link. Otherwise just sharing the link was enough :)

Answer (score 0):

First lostFocus will set the height to 1 and the onGotFocus will do multiplying 1*1 which is 1 effectively not changing anything.

Comment: you are right, and i just tried it with diffrent code. but is still dosnt work becuse, panles give focus to the first child add'd to them. check Ic link