# Locking menubar and statusbar as "always on top"

Tags: c#, scroll, statusbar, menubar

I have a windows form that includes one menubar at the top and one statusbar at the bottom. The window is scrollable, but when I scroll it lets say down, the menubar stays up so that I cant see it anymore, the same happens with the statusbar if i scroll up. Is there any way to make them visible at all times, like that they scroll with the screen, or as always on top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For creating a scrollable content, do this procedure :

1. Add a new window
2. Add MenuStrip and StatusStrip
3. Add **Panel** , set `AutoScroll` to `true` , `Dock` to `Fill`
4. Append all controls to panel.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But, I can only move it with the scrollbar, is there any way I could set the scrolling to the mouse wheel?

Comment: You have to put something inside the panel that can receive the focus.  A panel can't get the focus.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/17034