# ComboBox can't lose focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several comboboxes and all of them are manually entered text. After the combox selection couldn't lose focus. I used:

```
this.ActiveControl = null;
```

It works but the focus is going to the first control always.

Could you please suggest to fix this issue?

Comment: So you want all controls to lose focus? And when exactly do you want this to happen? Your question is far from clear. Maybe expand on a it for us -even a code sample.

Comment: I think its impossible to not have focus on any control. There always must be a control that is focused in winforms, but im not sure. Maybe you have to create invisible control and focus it. Vote up if im right.

Comment: If I only I had such dedication.

Comment: I click on the combobox and choose an item. Then I click the form but still can't lose the focus. I use mouse wheel to scroll the whole form.

Comment: See [Panel not getting focus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/719186)

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden control and set focus to that control. This way it will appear that nothing is focused. Something like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ActiveControl = HiddenControl;
}
```

Here is a Visual Studio 2012 project:
http://www.cameronjtinker.com/downloads/FocusTest.zip

Comment: do you want me to try creating hidden control for each combobox next to it?

Comment: No, you just need one hidden control and then you can assign it after your form `MouseClick` event or `ComboBox`es `SelectedIndexChanged` events.

Comment: Is textbox OK for hidden control?

Comment: Any control is fine for the hidden control as you won't be able to see it on the form.

Comment: I set the visible property to false. I used above code ActiveControl = textbox6; It doesn't work. I have the same problem.

Comment: You cannot set the focus to a hidden control.  Setting to a control that's off the window is okay.  Give it a Location with a large negative X property value.

Comment: I have tested the code in my answer in both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012. You can indeed set the active control of the form to a hidden control.