# Don't want button focus on form opening

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this problem... When my form opens, a button is focused. I don't want it bo me focused. I put on the form a little panel, that is not visible and set it as starting focus (also set `tabstop = false`). But still... the button is focused.

What could be the problem ?

I tried :

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   panel.Focus();
}
```

But still nothing happens, the button is still focused.

Comment: Remove focus from the button on load perhaps?

Comment: You may set [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) to `null` (`AcceptButton = null; //or any other button` instead of `panel.Focus();`).

Comment: No it's not a duplicate, because I tried many methods but still... the button is focused. Before writing this question i used the TabIndex to set the order of the controls but still... button is focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Panel control derives from ContainerControl.  Which provides common behavior for controls that act as containers for other controls.  Which includes *not* ever wanting to take the focus.  If you try to give them the focus they'll immediately pass it off to a child control.

There's a good reason for that, the user needs to be able to *see* which control has the focus.  So he knows where the keyboard strokes go.  And container controls don't have a way to display that.  Nor do they do anything reasonable with a keystroke.  You can certainly doctor a Panel control to make it a focusable control, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/17034) shows how.

But focus a bit on *why* you want to make it difficult for the user.  Maybe you are a bit to focused on the "blemish" of a focus rectangle?  If you really want to hide it then you can, it is pretty simple to do.  Just add a dummy button and give it a negative Location property and a TabIndex of 0.  Which moves it off the window, no longer visible to the user.  But still capable of taking the focus.  Solves the "blemish" problem, but at a risk of seriously confusing the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [`TabIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) of your controls so it will be focused in your wished order

Answer (score 0):

I think your panel cannot be focussed. Try a control inside your panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the button should not have focus when you open the form, then you need to correct the `TabIndex` property. The `TabIndex` property has an integer as value which specifies the order in which the controls get focus when tab key is pressed. If the control has `TabIndex` set to 0 then change it to some other value.

Or

you can also set control `TabStop` property to false.

documentation for [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) and [TabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Property Named `AcceptButtons`  of Form set it to `(none)`