# Change control focus on key press

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

When I press the Escape key I want to move the focus to the previous control.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what did you tried until this moment ? Code Snippets needed

Comment: also, the title is very generic, change it more close to the question

Comment: have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) :)

Comment: UserControl cannot get the focus. chekc this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus/3562449#3562449

Comment: Your user will *never* guess that pressing Escape does anything more than closing the window, dismissing the dialog.  It is very unclear why you think you need a non-standard UI like this.  Press Shift+Tab instead.  This otherwise can be done by overriding ProcessCmdKey() and calling the form's SelectNextControl() method with forward = false.

Comment: You could set the [tab index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you get focus on a control, log the control in a stack so you can always retrieve the previously focussed control.

Next use a keydown eventhandler on the controls and check for the escape key. If escape key is pressed, set focus to the top control in the stack.

Comment: thought the same, beat me by a minute ^^