# Textbox NO focus on load

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've searched a bit, and with google keyword "no" or "not" it get so general so I can't really find it

I have a textbox and I don't want the textbox to have the focus on load, so I've put the tabindex to 1 but it still get focus on load.

I know I could use method like `Select = false` but in my opinion it should not be required since the form itself should have focus on load not a textbox

Could use some help thank you

Comment: Which control has TabIndex = 0?

Comment: No control, I guess there's the problem but I don't want to create an invisible control to do that and It seems I can't but the tabindez = to the form itself

Comment: Is this Winforms, WPF, Web?  It's not very clear why "nothing" should have focus when you are presenting a form to a user.

Comment: Sorry for me being  unprecise, it's a simple windows form

Comment: You can try an offscreen TextBox or a [Selectable Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11570670/719186) maybe.

Comment: I know it will work, I'm just wondering about not taking memory space with a non used textbox :S I know it's not alot it's just about how it's coded I don't know if you get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)

  Dim focusBox As New TextBox
  focusBox.Location = New Point(0, -100)
  AddHandler focusBox.Leave, Sub()
                               focusBox.Dispose()
                             End Sub
  Me.Controls.Add(focusBox)
  focusBox.Select()
End Sub
```

It won't pollute the designer and as soon as a control gets a focus, it will dispose of itself.

Comment: haahhahaah, I know you don't understand why it's funny to me but yea thank you sir, I guess it will do the trick :)