# Trouble creating KeyDown event in Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, keydown

I am currently working on winform that has a panel on it. I need to be able to use the up, down, left and right arrows on the panel and get something to happen.

I tried adding the event with this line of code:

```
            (MainPanel as Control).KeyDown += 
                                 new KeyEventHandler(panelKeyPressEventHandler);
```

With this KeyDown code:

```
        public void panelKeyPressEventHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Here I am!");

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.L:
                {

                    break;
                }
            case Keys.R:
                {

                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Up:
                {
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Down:
                {
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Right:
                {
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Left:
                {
                    break;
                }

        }
    }
```

Thus far, even when I guarantee focus is set on the panel, I am unable to get it to enter this KeyDown event function for anything. :( I can hit keys all day long and nothing happens.

Does anyone have any suggestion on the best way to handle up,down,left and right arrows being pressed when a panel has focus?

Thank you!

Comment: What is it you want to have happen?  It's likely that you would want to put some other control in there, `Dock.Fill` it, and then react on that instead.  You can do stuff with a Panel, but it's more useful for just holding the stuff you _do_ want to play with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Panel not getting focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus)

Answer (score 4):

Panel control cannot get focus and not selectable also. Focused controls can only get "key events". You likely need to override `ProcessCmdKey` in your form or `UserControl`.

You need to set `KeyPreview = true`

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch(keydata)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
             break;
        ...
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: A bit too broad in scope if there is a lot of stuff on the form.  Really have no idea what the goal is.  This giant catch-all could prove counter-productive.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I don't think how this is counter-productive. Do you know key events not supported in panel control?

Comment: I said it _could be_ counter-productive.  Using `ProcessCmdKey` as your first option for getting key presses is sloppy.  Instead, use a `Panel` for its intended purpose and put in a control that _is designed_ to capture keys.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Agree.. :)