# How to move up/down a Panel using keys

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keypress

I've a picturebox on a form window. In this picturebox I want to move the panel (as a circle panel) up and down using keys only if I click on it.

IE: there are 3 panels having the following X,Y:

- panel1(5,5)  panel2(10,5)  panel3 (15,5)

So if I click on panel1 I get focus on it and only it and then if I click on upKey or DownKey I move this panel up or down in the picturebox. Clicking on another object you leave the focus on the panel.

Same thing if I click on panel2 or panel3.

Any help and tip is appreciated.

### Thanks

UPDATE #2

I did some changes and now I can move up or down a panel by clicking on it.
The problem now is that if I click on panel1 to get focus and move it up or down, it moves with panel2 togheter. I want to move just panel1 if i click on it..
Setting up a new bool property of the panel object that enable or disable it on click it seems that doesn't work and by clicking on panel and then on up/down keys nothing happens.

Following there is the full code of my two updated classes:

Class CircleButton (panel)

```
public class CircleButton : Panel
{
    //Properties to draw circle
    float radius;
    public float Radius
    {
        get { return radius; }
        set
        {
            radius = value;
            this.Size = new Size((int)Radius, (int)Radius);
        }
    }


    Point centre;
    public Point Centre
    {
        get { return centre; }

        set
        {
            centre = value;
            this.Location = Centre;
        }
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    bool active;
    public bool Active
    {
        get { return active; }

        set
        {
            active = value;
            this.Enabled = active;
        }
    }

    public CircleButton()
    {
        //Default Values
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        Radius = 1;
        Centre = new Point(0, 0);
        Active = false;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        //Defines a graphic path and set it as the panel's region
        //For custom region use different path's
        if (centre != null)
        {
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            path.AddEllipse(0, 0, radius, radius);
            this.Region = new Region(path);
            path.Dispose();
        }
    }


    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        Focus();
    }

}
```

Form class

```
public partial class FormView : Form
{      
    private int _x;
    private int _y;
    CircleButton panel;

    public FormView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _x = 20 ;
        _y = 20 ;            
    }

    protected void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Display Message
        //panel = (CircleButton)sender;
        //MessageBox.Show(panel.Message);          
        panel.Focus();
        panel.Active = true;

        panel.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(panel_KeyDown);
    }

    private void panel_KeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel.Active == true)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                _y -= 10;
                Invalidate();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                _y += 10;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        panel = new CircleButton();
        panel.Centre = new Point(_x, _y);
        panel.Radius = 10;
        panel.BackColor = Color.Red;
        panel.Active = false;

        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.Click += new EventHandler(panel_Click) ;

        panel = new CircleButton();
        panel.Centre = new Point(_x+50, _y);
        panel.Radius = 10;
        panel.BackColor = Color.Black;
        panel.Active = false;

        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.Click += new EventHandler(panel_Click);
    }



}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You already have a realy good start. Now for the moving part. If I were you I would make a `Boolean` lets call it isMoving for now. If a panel gets clicked isMoving is  set to `true`. Based on that `Boolean` you can make keydown events in a `timer_Tick` event that loops forever.but only work if your `Boolean` is true. Then just ++ the location with desired values. If you do this for every panel you use it should work the way you want it to. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I've a problem, if I click on the panel, the form stops receive inputs and freezes :(

Comment: Can you show me the code that you added? Cause I don't think I can try to help you based on what I'm reading here.

Comment: I added this function in CircleButton class `public bool isMoving { get; set; }` and implemented inside the form. I edit the main question post adding the form class that implement the CircleButton class.

Comment: @TimvanGool you can look at the full code in the main post. Thank you!

Comment: btw now I've problems in the form class at `panel_Click` method because of `e.KeyCode` :( I'm stuck

Comment: I might know what your problem is. Expect some code to explain it soon. Writing it right now

Comment: @TimvanGool my problem is that I don't understand how to use the `e.KeyCode == Keys.Up` or `== Keys.Down` because it says that `System.args does not contain a definition for KeyCode`.. try it if you want and see.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)   
    {
        if (isMoving == true)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                _y -= 10;
                Invalidate();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                _x -= 10;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }     
    }
```

The problem you're having is that your `if statements` are not in a `KeyDown event`. They way you're using the `e.KeyCode` is correct. If you need any more information on KeyDown and/or KeyPress event i suggest clicking [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx)

I hope this helps if you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you it's more clear now.. another question: how to do the overload? because doing like this: `panel.Click += new EventHandler(panel_KeyDown);` produces an error: `No overload for panel_KeyDown matches delegate System.Handler`

Comment: Thats a problem on its own. By default panels do not have a `KeyDown` event. Heres a link that should help you fix this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079373/trouble-creating-keydown-event-in-panel

Comment: I updated my code and now it seems to intercept the key events. By the way it still doesn't work as I would because setting up a boolean property that changes if you click on the panel seems to not work at all..

Comment: I hope you know that you can't use the same boolean for all panels. Each panel needs his own boolean otherwise they would interfere with eachother.

Comment: you are right but I guess I'm setting the boolean for each panel as its own property.. or not? Looking at the code I've updated you can see how it actually works. I guess it's a `sender` problem instead but I don't know hot to specify that the sender is panel1 instead or panel2.

Comment: Quick question, are your panels moving or not?

Comment: yes panels are moving up or down, togheter! But only if I remove the boolean condition `if(panel.Active == true)`

Comment: This is just me thinking out loud a the moment. But I think that all your panels are the same panel and all focus at the same time because there is nothing that makes them unique, also you give each new panel the same event that gets called. I might be wrong here and please correct me if I am.

Comment: probably you are right (again) about the panel that's not unique.. do you have an idea to make it unique each time I make a new one?
I thought making the panel from an own class was enough to make it unique. Take in mind that I need to create panels dynamically so I can't know before how many panels I need.

Comment: EDIT: I guess the problem is not the panel unique but the sender.. Because the two panels have different colors and location and the sender results to be the second panel (the black one). How can I fix this situation?