# Panel focus probleem

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a simple game: "Gomoku" or "Five in a Row" in a Windows.Form application.
My program looks like this when is started and I **don't press Tab key**:
[image: Normal look]

But when I **press Tab key** it looks like this:
[image: Wrong look]

That board is a panel and every time I press Left, Right, Up, Down, A, D, W and S it's moving that two X from corners in the selected direction.

When I was presing Legt and Right it was switching tabPages so I added a textBox and I set focus to him:

```
if (textBox1.CanFocus) 
    textBox1.Focus();
```

[image: Design look]

This is how I added background color and the lines on the board (game panel.

```
private void PuneFundal(Graphics g)
    {
        g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(150, 124, 92));
    }

private void DeseneazaLinie(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
    g.DrawLine(p, p1, p2);
}

private void TrasareLinii(Graphics g)
{
    for (int i = 6, k = 0; k < 20; i += 16, k++)
        DeseneazaLinie(g, new Point(5, i), new Point(309, i));
    for (int i = 6, k = 0; k < 20; i += 16, k++)
        DeseneazaLinie(g, new Point(i, 5), new Point(i, 309));
}

private void Start_game()
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
    Graphics g = game_panel.CreateGraphics();

    PuneFundal(g);
    TrasareLinii(g);
}
```

What can I do to work well when I press Tab key?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;` that means you set `tabPage2` as the currently selected tab page, therefore it gains focus.

I recommend following solutions:

1. You can always set focus of TextBox1 after selecting a tab page.
2. Or use **custom selectable panel** which accepts focus. See [@HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562235/panel-not-getting-focus).

Comment: I tryed both of them but I get the same result