# Show button only when focus is on textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Is this possible to display button on Windows Form only when focus is on specific textbox?

Tried that with this approach:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Visible = true;
    }

    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Visible = false;
    }
```

No luck, because button click does not work then, because button is hidden ***immediately*** after textbox lost focus, preventing it from firing `button3_Click(/*...*/) { /*...*/ }` event.

Now I'm doing it like that:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Visible = true;
    }

    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //button3.Visible = false;
        DoAfter(() => button3.Visible = false);
    }

    private async void DoAfter(Action action, int seconds = 1)
    {
        await Task.Delay(seconds*1000);
        action();
    }
```

Form now waits for a second and only then hides `button3`.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: try use button.visible=false in another control enter event not in button control.So this button visible change  when another control got focus

Comment: Actually there's a ton of other controls and user could focus on any of those. Making events of every field is not really OK.

Comment: use the **textBox1.GotFocus** and **textBox1.LostFocus**

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo It works exactly the same.

Comment: If you always need the click button event, then hide the button after button clicked.

Comment: User could ignore that button and continue to another control where I must hide button also. Hiding on click could never happen and therefore it would be visible always.

Comment: Have you thought about making the button visible only while there is a value in it? It seems like you are wanting a user input into the textbox.

Comment: Not really, because what that button would do is open another form from which I could select specific text for `textBox2`. User should be able to open that form independently of `textBox2`'s value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to display the button only when focus is on specific textbox *or the focus is on the button*.

To do this you can check the `Focused` property of `button3` in the `Leave` event of `textBox2` and only hide the button if the button doesn't have focus. Note that the button will get focus *before* the `Leave` event of `textBox2` fires.

You will then need to hide the button in the scenario where `button3` loses focus and the focus moves to somewhere other than `textBox2`. You can use exactly the same technique here by handling the `Leave` event of `button3` and only hiding `button3` if `textBox2` does not have focus.

The following code should fit your requirements:

```
private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!button3.Focused)
    {
        button3.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void button3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!textBox2.Focused)
    {
        button3.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.Visible = true;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button clicked");
}
```

Comment: You're the **MAN**! It works as expected without additional controls or events on every other field. I now recall that I've tried something with `Control.Focused`, but failed miserably. Your answer works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not work with the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the TextBox?

```
private void textBox2_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.Visible = true;
}
```

Then hide the button on the click event.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
    button3.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: `Control.CanFocus` does not have a setter. And GotFocus/LostFocus works the same as Enter/Leave - click doesn't fire.

Comment: Apologies, was confusing it with a WPF property.

Comment: No prob. I'm marking this answer as useful. I don't know anything about WPF, but if CanFocus does what I think it does (if true, focus does not change in program and is left where it was), then it should work in my opinion.

Comment: About that edit: as I said in another answer - user could also ignore that button and do nothing with it, so `button3_Click` event could be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

How about you add a Panel and place the button and text boxes in that panel and when user `MouseHover`s that Panel then display the button...

This way user would be able to click on the button...

This is the event you are looking for, I think...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx

**UPDATE:**

```
var textboxFocussed = false;        
private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textboxFocussed = true;
}

private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textboxFocussed = false;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
private void Panel_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.Visible = textboxFocussed;
}

private void Panel_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.Visible = false;
}
```

Here are the details of the [Panel Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel_events.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that, because task is to show/hide button on textbox focus/blur.

Comment: You can set a flag on Focus of the text box and then use that in the Panel's Hover event

Comment: What about user tabbing to control? Mouse could be completely out of the form in that case. So, hover is not an option, too.

Comment: In that case you might need to use `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events for the Panel

Comment: Panel can't get focus, because it is a container. Answer given in following question has implementation of focus, but that's much more effort than delaying button hiding. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/1745228

Answer (score 0):

you can add **Enter** event handler for all controls on form at **Load**. Just make sure to skip the controls on which you want to show the button.

```
    List<string> strControlException = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        strControlException.Add("btnMain");
        strControlException.Add("txtMain");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count;i++ )
        {
            if (!strControlException.Contains(Controls[i].Name))
            {
                Controls[i].Enter += new EventHandler(hideButton);
            }
        }
    }

    private void txtMain_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnMain.Visible = true;
    }

    private void hideButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnMain.Visible = false;
    }
```

btnMain (Button you want to Manipulate) and txtMain (Which controls the vibility of the button) are the controls in contention here

Add more controls on the form to test.

Explanation for the above code :

1. First initialize a list with the names of controls that should show the Button
2. On Form Load add an Event handler to all controls (except the one in our list)
3. In the handler function hide the button. (You might want to perform more logic here based on the control that called this function)
4. Button is hidden by default and only on textbox Enter event we show the button.