# Different Windows OS, different behavior of FlowLayoutPanel scroll event

Tags: c#, winforms, mousemove, flowlayoutpanel

I have a project started where I use two `FlowLayoutPanel` (FLP) in a `SplitContainer`.
The scroll bar of those FLP will behave different on Windows 7 than on Windows 10. 
On W7 scrolling is continouslly, when mouse moving. In W10 it scrolls after mouse moving stops.
What should I do?

(Extra info: In W7 scroll wheel does not work when mouse is over the FLP and object inside. On W10, it scrolls using mouse wheel.)

Comment: Win10 made a big change with its "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" system option.  Turned on by default.  This makes the mouse more consistent with the way it works in, say, a browser.  Which lets you scroll the page no matter where the mouse is located.  Previously the wheel notification was sent to the window with the focus.  Makes a big difference to FLP when it doesn't contain any controls that can receive the focus.  In other words, when it isn't "active".  Retrofit the panel to be scrollable in Win7 with [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/17034).

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant . This will solve the problem in Extra info, but not the first one and the most important. W7 continous scroll vs W10 scroll at the end of the moving mouse event.

Comment: No idea what that even means, you scroll a window by operating the wheel, not by moving the mouse.  You'll have to show repro code to get ahead.

Comment: You can scroll a window by dragging the scroll bar button. When dragging, on W7 is cursive scroll, on W10 it will scroll when you stop moving the mouse.