# Capturing the KeyDown event on PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I know there is no **KeyDown** event for *PictureBox*, but I really want to capture that event. I was using the Form's KeyDown event but it becomes problematic when there are too many widgets, so I don't have any choice but enclose the key events to the PictureBox. In the documentation, it says that **PreviewKeyDown** is used to capture key events when the focus is on PictureBox. I have tried doing that by setting the focus on the widget with **MouseEnter**, but it just doesn't listen for key events.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.H:
                    MessageBox.Show("Pressed button");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Focus();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ActiveControl = null;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make a Custom Control, derived from PictureBox, then add `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);` in its Constructor. Since you're there, you can also override `OnKeyDown`, and raise the event, if needed. PreviewKeyDown will work anyway.

Comment: Wrong focus.  You could not tell you had this bug because of the other essential GUI feature that is missing, actually being able to *see* which widget has the focus.  Drawing a focus rectangle is really easy, example [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/17034).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving focus to the FORM, not the PictureBox.

Change:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Focus();
}
```

To:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Focus();
}
```