# Detect Key pressing on a Panel in C#

Tags: c#

So I have a panel and looking to get when a key is pressed. So I intentionally have it attached to the Panel as I would need to I believe have this.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace unchained{
    public class Dungeon{ 
        public Panel DungeonPanel(){
            Panel gamePanel = new();
            
            Button quitGame = new();
            quitGame.BackColor = Color.FromArgb( 255, 255 , 255);
            quitGame.Width = 200;
            quitGame.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(395, 150);
            quitGame.Text = "Quit Game";
            quitGame.Click += quitGamePlay;

            gamePanel.Width = 800;
            gamePanel.Height = 600;
            gamePanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            gamePanel.Visible = false;
            //(Sender, e) => newGame(Sender,e);
            gamePanel.KeyPress += (Sender, e) =>detectKeyPress(Sender, e);
            gamePanel.Controls.Add(quitGame); 

            void quitGamePlay(Object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                ScreenManager.screen = "Main";
                ScreenManager.HandleScreenChanges(ScreenManager.pan1, ScreenManager.pan2, ScreenManager.pan3, ScreenManager.pan4);
            }

            void detectKeyPress(Object ? sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
                Console.Write("1");
                if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.F){Console.Write("Test");}
            }

            return gamePanel;
        }
    }
}
```

When pressing on the F key nothing is happening. But This does not seem to be the issue. As I do not even get the Console write to appear either. So this would seem to point to the fact that the method isn't even being called

Comment: A `Panel` doesn't raise keyboard events. Only controls that can receive focus will raise such events and, if its `KeyPreview` is set to `true`, so will a form. That's why, if you use the `Properties` window in the designer to create event handlers, the `KeyPress` and other keyboard events isn't even listed for a `Panel` control.

Comment: By the way, don't try to debug using `Console.Write` or the like. Set a breakpoint on the method and use the actual debugger.

Comment: So I get that the issue is that the Panel does not have focus. And needs to get and control switch from the Form to the Panel. I tried the following. (MyPanel as Control).KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MyKeyPressEventHandler). And seems to move me in the right direction, but errors that char is not valid. As for the console write I do that as I am intentionally not using the designer.

Comment: Panel was designed to be a container control, hosting other controls.  As such it can't receive the focus and thus can't receive keystrokes.  That is [fixable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/17034).

Answer (score 0):

Casting the Panel to a Control does not change the fact that the Panel does not receive keyboard input.

There are two plausible approaches here. The first would be to derive from Form instead of Panel. Form can receive keyboard input. The second would be to place a transparent key-receiving control on top of the Panel.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are trying to use `KeyPress` for the panel. It will not trigger for the Keys and only trigger for the character key is pressed and released. and Also the panel is not intended for direct text input. By default, keyboard events are not received unless it is focused.

Try to use `KeyDown` and change the event handler in you code as,

```
gamePanel.KeyDown += detectKeyPress;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like people have already said, the panel itself does not raise the `KeyPress` Event.
I went with [@sjb-sjb's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78115029/14448817) and used the `KeyPress` Event of the Form. You also have to enable `KeyPreview` on the Form for this to work.

If your `gamePanel` is directly inside your Form the easiest way to access it is probably via the `Parent` property, like so:

```
var parent = gamePanel.Parent as Form;
if (parent != null)
{
    parent.KeyPreview = true;
    parent.KeyPress += DetectKeyPress;
}
```

But keep in mind that `DetectKeyPress` is now triggered on every key-press regardless if your panel is focused or not!

Also `e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.F` does only detect uppercase F's.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an event handler.
[Take a look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMejp.png)

if you are using visual studio you can add events like key down or key up to your program. Just double click on the texts that I have illustrated in the picture.

I chose form1 in this picture. However, you can use any panel and set an event handler for it.

A panel's key down event works only when it is focused.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend rethinking the whole thing: all the previous answers are giving a lot of good hints on how to do it the right way. Neverthless, you can achieve a result by swapping your Panel control with a custom one (based on the answers of @sjb-sjb and @Ottxr):

```
public class SelectablePanel : Panel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor subscribes to the ParentChanged event, so when the control
    /// is added to a hosting control an event will fire.
    /// </summary>
    public SelectablePanel()
    {
        ParentChanged += SelectablePanel_ParentChanged;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Event fires when the parent of this control changes.
    /// If it is a Form control, then gets a reference to it and subscribes to its KeyDown event.
    /// </summary>
    private void SelectablePanel_ParentChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent is null) { return; }
        var parentForm = Parent as Form;
        if (parentForm is null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent control of the SelectablePanel is not a Form");
            return;
        }
        parentForm.KeyPreview = true;
        parentForm.KeyDown += detectKeyPress;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the KeyDown event of the hosting Form control.
    /// </summary>
    private void detectKeyPress(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // You can focus the panel here.
        Select();
        Console.Write("1");
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F) { Console.Write("Test"); }
    }
}
```

After the swap you'll have:

```
public class Dungeon
{
    public SelectablePanel DungeonPanel()
    {
        SelectablePanel gamePanel = new();
        Button quitGame = new();

        quitGame.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
        quitGame.Width = 200;
        quitGame.Location = new Point(395, 150);
        quitGame.Text = "Quit Game";
        quitGame.Click += quitGamePlay;

        gamePanel.Width = 800;
        gamePanel.Height = 600;
        gamePanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
        gamePanel.Visible = true;
        //(Sender, e) => newGame(Sender,e);
        //gamePanel.KeyPress += (Sender, e) => detectKeyPress(Sender, e);
        gamePanel.Controls.Add(quitGame);

        void quitGamePlay(Object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScreenManager.screen = "Main";
            ScreenManager.HandleScreenChanges(ScreenManager.pan1, ScreenManager.pan2, ScreenManager.pan3, ScreenManager.pan4);
        }

        return gamePanel;
    }
}
```

This is a *horrible* way to solve your problem. Still, it may or may not work for you. Just keep in mind every other subscription to the hosting Form's KeyPress event will fire detectKeyPress, as @Ottxr pointed out.

Optionally, instead of getting a reference to the parent control in the ParentChanged event, you can inject a reference to a Form in the SelectablePanel class constructor.